# Relation of Euler number of a line bundle over a Riemann surface and a section of it with finitely many isolated singularities

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Suppose $M$ is a compact Riemann surface and $E\to M$ a holomorphic line bundle over $M$. Also suppose $s:M\to E$ is a section with finitely many isolated singularities (undefined points, and not removable). At each of these singularities, we can define the order of $s$ since we can locally regard $s$ as a holomorphic complex function. Is there a relation of these orders and the euler number of $E$? (I'm expecting the following result: $e(E)$ is the sum of these orders, since there is a similar result relating the euler number of a vector bundle and a section with finitely many zeros.)

Comment: You're right, provided you also count (with multiplicities) the zeroes of the section. Then you get $\chi(E) = Z-P$, just like the argument principle.

Comment: Hint: Each pole locally looks like a function $f(z)=z^{-n}, n>0$, on the closed unit disk. But for $|z|=1$ this function can be also written as $g(z)=\bar{z}^n$, which defines a smooth extension to the unit disk. Now, count the oriented intersection number of the corresponding section with the zero section.